# firebase security rule which will prevent the updation or deletion of existing node

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

for example, if I have created a node (book) which have a child (author) with value ("name of author"). What I want is that in future no one can update or delete this child node. I know it is possible with firebase security rules but I am not able to figure out the optimal way to do so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could write a database rule to only allow creating new data and not editing anything once it's been written.

This allows you to create a new `book` if no data already exists at the `$key` location. It also ensures that `newData` exists and that `author` is a `string` variable.

```
{
  "rules": {
    "book": {
      "$key": {
        "author": {
          ".validate": "newData.isString()"
        },
        ".write": "data.val() == null && newData.val() != null"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: This ensures the data can't be deleted, but doesn't yet enforce that it can't be changed. For that, add `newData.val() === data.val()`.

Comment: Shouldn't `data.val() === null` enforce a `create` write only, it won't allow `update` or `delete`?

Comment: Hmmm... that's a good point. It probably does, so I'm not sure why I use the other conditional then. Well... both might work.

Comment: I use Firebase-Bolt and it renders a create as `".write": "data.val() == null"` so it could be even simpler perhaps? All three solutions would work!

Comment: Ah... that's a "write once". Nice!